# Integration testing C# WebAPI asp.NET Framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to write integration tests in C# for my C# asp.NET Framework 4.6.1 WebAPI which contains simple CRUD functionalities.

I have found little to no documentation on making automated integration tests for .NET Framework 4.6.1 using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.4. 
I've only found relatively old articles and video's on making integration tests for .NET Core using Xunit and Nunit, but ran into a lot of compatibility issues while trying to somehow make them work on .NET Framework 4.6.1 and WebApi 5.2.4.

I know this question could be considered primarily opinion based, but I would really appreciate any help on the matter.

**How to write automated tests for an .NET Framework 4.6.1 Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.4 application?**

- Which packages could I use?
- How do I configure these packages properly?
- How should I use these packages?

I currently do not use Owin for hosting my application, but invoke my configurations in Global.asax, but I could create a solution configuration which builds the project using Owin if needed.

Comment: I don't believe you "ran into a lot of compatibility issues". Those are well supported on .NET Framework. Show more info please.

Comment: @LexLi Could you help me out by telling me which packages you used which are well supported? I'm relatively new to c# asp.net and I'm really stuck here.

Comment: Both Xunit and NUnit are well supported on .NET Framework.

Comment: @LexLi For writing unit tests, yes: I've had no problems so far. But I need to write integration tests. I've read a lot about those today and I'm pretty sure I need some way to host the application (in-memory) and a way to communicate to it like a normal http-client would.

Comment: I am confused by you. It is just a simple Web API, so why cannot you host it on IIS (assuming its production environment would also be on IIS) and then write a few test cases in NUnit or Xunit to get the job done. Yes, you might use OWIN to self host it and test, but why should you?

Comment: @Lex Li the integration tests go deeper than that since for a TestSetup you have to create an integration test db, migrate data from your dev db to the integration test db, do your integration test and then close all connections and teardown the integration test db. This is the type of documentation that Microsoft is completely lacking for Web API - there's not even an 'Integration Test' section for the API docs like there is for .NET Core. Joas - did you ever find decent documentation for this? Like you, I've found it for all other .net frameworks except Web API. :(

Comment: Integration testing is application/project dependent, so it relies on your own understanding of your project and environment to effectively develop the test cases. My integration test db and processes would be obviously different from yours. for example. So I don't agree that's something Microsoft should be responsible.

Comment: @Joas Thanks, I'm so stuck. If you want some extra points, you can post your answer on my question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936781/nunit-integration-tests-on-web-api-how-to-create-destroy-integration-test-db

Answer (score 4):

After reading the comments it sounds like you’re looking for owin TestServer.

https://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've read the article earlier today, but since it was from 2012 I doubted it's reliability (as we all know, a lot can change in 6 years). It also doesn't mention anything about the owin TestServer. I've also worked with the owin TestServer earlier today, but it doesn't seem to support .NET Framework 4.6.1 Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.4 applications, since it references interfaces only found in Microsoft.AspNetCore (For example: an IApplicationBuilder is passed to the Startup.Configure method, which takes an IAppBuilder in Microsoft.AspNet instead)

Comment: Look at the older version of the owin test server, they should have the correct interfaces.